How can I limit a field to 2 ranges of numbers?
I have a number field that takes numbers between 0.25 and 5
I would like for it to also have the option to take between 15 ~ 300... so a user can input either:
0.25 ~ 5 OR 15 ~ 300
<input class="form-control square" min="0.25" max="5" step="0.01" type="number" name="hashtag">

This is the current element

You will need JavaScript for that, only HTML cannot help it

Ah, that is fine. can you perhaps help me with that?

You will need an interactive element such as a button to allow the user to toggle between the two given ranges, and then control the input with JavaScript.
Something like this:
HTML
<input id="range-input" class="form-control square" min="0.25" max="5" step="0.01" type="number" name="hashtag">
<button id="toggle-range">Range</button>
<p id="info-text">Current range: 0.25 - 5</p>

JavaScript
const input = document.querySelector("#range-input");
const button = document.querySelector("#toggle-range");
const info = document.querySelector("#info-text");

button.addEventListener("click", (event) => {
  event.preventDefault();
  let min = "0.25", max = "5";
  if (input.min === min) {
    min = "15", max = "300";    
  }
  input.min = min, input.max = max;
  info.innerText = `Current range: ${min} - ${max}`
});

